# Getting null pointer exception when trying to merge sort array of a class

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have a well formed class called General with variables for ID, name, and age. Two ints and a string. I then have a GeneralRosters class that opens a serializable file, reads in records, sorts the records, and closes the file. I use a separate MergeSort class to sort the records. Whenever I run my tester program, I keep getting a null pointer exception for my MergeSort class. I know the records were read into my array correctly because I can output the entire list after it's read in. Any idea what's going wrong? I'll paste my code below.
[image: error message]

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class General implements Serializable {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private static final long serialVersionUID =  6894788911163027404L;   //not an instnace variable,needed for serial file

    public General() {
        setID(0);
        setName("");
        setAge(0);
    }
    public General(int ID, String name, int age) {
        setID(ID);
        setName(name);
        setAge(age);
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return ("ID: " + ID + "\n Name: \t" + name + "\n Age: \t" + age);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GeneralRosters
{
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private General [] roster = new General[20];
    // **** SORT ROUTINE *******
    public void sortRoster(){
        System.out.println("** In sortRoster **");
        MergeSort mergeSort = new MergeSort();
        mergeSort.sort(roster, 0, roster.length-1);

    }
    //  ******* OPEN FILE ROUTINE *******
    public void openFile(){
        System.out.println("** In openFile **");
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("generalMaster.ser"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("can't open or accesss file  " + ioException + "\n");
        }
    } 

 //******* READ FILE and LOAD ARRAY ROUTINE *******
    public void readRecords(){
        System.out.println("** In readRecords **");
        General  record;
        int count = 0;   //Used to populate array in while loop

        System.out.printf("%-12s%-20s%-12s\n","ID","Name","Age");
        try {
            while((record = (General) input.readObject()) != null)  {
                roster[count] = record;
                count++;
                System.out.printf("%-12d%-20s%-12d\n",record.getID(), record.getName(), record.getAge());
            }
        }
        catch(EOFException e){
            System.out.println("....catch ...." + e + "\n");
            return;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException eclassNotFound){
            System.out.println("....catch ...." + eclassNotFound + "\n");
        }
        catch(IOException eIO){
            System.out.println("....catch ...." + eIO + "\n");
        }
    } 
    public void closeFile(){
        System.out.println("** In closeFile **");
        try {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioExcetion) {
            System.err.println("Error closing file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }  
}
```

```
public class MergeSort {
    public void sort(General[] data, int low, int high) {
        if ((high - low) >= 1) {
            int middle1 = (low + high) / 2;
            int middle2 = middle1 + 1;

            sort(data, low, middle1);
            sort(data, middle2, high);

            merge(data, low, middle1, middle2, high);
        }
    }

    public void merge(General[] data, int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right) {
        int leftIndex = left;
        int rightIndex = middle2;
        int combinedIndex = left;
        General[] combined = new General[data.length];

        while (leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right) {
            if(data[leftIndex].getID() <= data[rightIndex].getID()) {
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
            }else {
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
            }
        }
        if(leftIndex == middle2) {
            while(rightIndex <= right) {
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
            }
        }else {
            while(leftIndex <= middle1) {
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
            }
        }

        for(int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
            data[i] = combined[i];
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class GeneralRostersTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        GeneralRosters application = new GeneralRosters();
        application.openFile();
        application.readRecords();
        application.closeFile();
        application.sortRoster();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash The array I am sending to my sort method isn't empty so I don't know why i'm getting the error. In the image it shows all the records in the array outputted to the console.

Comment: could you try adding `System.out.printf("%-12d%-20s%-12d\n",roster[count-1].getID(), roster[count-1].getName(), roster[count-1].getAge());` right after the original `System.out.printf` in the reading loop? What does it print?

Comment: sorry, in one of the first edits, you’ve replaced `roster[0]` with `roster[count]` inside the reading loop; did you apply the same change to your code? using `roster[0]` would explain the `null`-s in the `roster` array even if each `record` is not `null` and can be printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't checked `data[leftIndex]` and `data[rightIndex]` for `null` before accessing data from them.

Replace

```
if(data[leftIndex].getID() <= data[rightIndex].getID()) {
    combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
}
```

with

```
if(data[leftIndex] != null && data[rightIndex] != null) {
    if(data[leftIndex].getID() <= data[rightIndex].getID()) {
        combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
    }
}
```

On a side note, you are not checking `null` while reading the file. When there is no object left to read, `input.readObject()` will return `null` which needs to be checked in the `while` loop so that the control does not enter the loop body.

Replace

```
while(true) {
    record = (General) input.readObject();
```

with

```
while((record = (General) input.readObject()) != null) {
```

Comment: I made the suggested change and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: @ConnorS. - I've updated the answer. I hope, it solves your problem.

Comment: It seems to be working now. After I made the changes it didn't work at first, but eclipse was trying to run an older build. Thank you for the help.

Comment: but wait, @ConnorS., have you figured out why there are `null`-s in the array at all?

Comment: @sainaen Eclipse was running an older build of my program that didn't have any of the changes I made incorporated. My serial file doesn't have any nulls so it was something changed in the code. It's likely it was still using roster[0] in my readRecord method instead of roster[count]. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ahh, okay. thanks! I was going slightly crazy trying to figure out why I don’t get any issues running your code locally. :)